# Java web start successfully launching jnlp, but does not create an entry in the cache viewer under "Applications"

Tags: java, java-web-start

We have an application which is deployed by java web start. The application can be started successfully, but it does not create an entry in the "Applications" list of the Java Cache Viewer. But the resources used are all listed in the "Ressources" section.

The jnlp does create the desktop-shortcut as also the entry in the programs folder (if install is set to true) and it can be successfully launched by those.

The following is the structure of the jnlp:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp 
    spec="6.0+" 
    href="XXX.jnlp"
    codebase="127.0.0.1"
    >
    <information>
        <title>The Title</title>
        <vendor>The Vendor</vendor>
        <description>Web Start</description>
        <icon href="images/logo32x32.png"/>
        <icon kind="splash" href="images/splash.png"/>
        <shortcut online="true" install="false">  
            <desktop/>   
            <menu submenu="XXX"/>
        </shortcut> 
    </information>
    <update check="always" policy="always" />
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.8+" />
        <jar href="xxx/mainClient.jar" main="true"/>
        <jar href="xxx/lib/SomeLib.jar" />
        <jar href="xxx/lib/SomeOtherLib.jar" />
    </resources>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security> 

    <application-desc 
        main-class="xxx.xxx.MainForm" 
        name="XXX">
            <argument>-Duser.language=en</argument>
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

I also tried many other combinations of flags:

- with or without offline-allowed
- with or without the jar elements main attribute
- shortcut elements online/install attribute to true/false
- update elements check attribute to timeout/always

What else could I check?

When starting a demo application from here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/misc/index.html

it gets successfully added as an "Application" in the Java Cache Viewer. I did test our jnlp on several systems which all show the same problem.

Comment: Are you running windows? Might there be another (64 or 32 bit) java control panel?

Comment: I am running a 64-bit Windows 7, java has version 1.8.0_121-b13. I started javacpl.exe now from both paths (32 and 64 bit). Both panels show the same content (ie. resources are there, but no entry in "Applications").

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: Thank you for the JaNeLa hint. But does JaNeLa know the spec >= 7.0? It tells me for example, the attribute 'install' may not be in element 'shortcut'. But that is exacly how oracle defines it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html

JaNeLa also says the security element is invalid, that it expects {resources, apllication-desc, applet-desc, installer-desc}.

Comment: Hmm, well, although the oracle example defines that attribute, that example seem to be faulty. The attribute 'install' needs spec="7.0", but the example from oracle defines "6.0+".
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html

Comment: I stripped down my jnlp so it matches the jnlp of one of the oracle demos, but it still won't list our app in the cache viewer (started locally or from webserver). The only difference left now is that our jnlp is using resources (some jars). All jars have all attributes needed in their manifest and all are signed. There is no warning in the java console and the app works fine, also JaNeLa is happy with the jnlp. I definitely ran out of ideas to fix this.